# Process inputstream is not returning process input (OSX)

Tags: java, macos, process, terminal

I'm trying to get the output of a process I launch using a process builder however the output seems to look like something from applescript and not the actual output of the process:

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getJavaOutput());
}

public static String getJavaOutput() {
    try {
        //kill -9 $(ps -p $PPID -o ppid=)
        String output = "";
        ProcessBuilder macBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("osascript", "-e",
                "tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"jps -lV && exit\"");
        Process p2 = macBuilder.start();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p2.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            output += line + System.getProperty("line.separator");
        }
        return output;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    return null;
}
```

Expected Output:

```
2680 sun.tools.jps.Jps
1289
```

Actual Output:

```
tab 1 of window id 742
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your method to :

```
public static String getJavaOutput() {
    try {
        String output = "";
        ProcessBuilder macBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", "jps -lV && exit");
        Process p2 = macBuilder.start();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p2.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            output += line + System.getProperty("line.separator");
        }
        return output;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```